# Parsing HTML by PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have this html code in my website:

```
<span class="adPage__content__price-feature__prices__price__currency" itemprop="priceCurrency" content="€"> € </span>
```

And I try to parse currency by my php script:

```
preg_match("/(?<=itemprop=\"priceCurrency\"\ content=\").*?(?=\>)/",$ec,$matches_curr);
```

And it gives me: €"

But I need to parse only: €

How I can get it?

Comment: [PHP Simple HTML DOM parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html) works pretty nicely

Comment: i need like this, not using DOM parser